# glusterfs error when delete directory - Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: linux, storage, mount, glusterfs

I have mounted `glusterfs` on my CentOS 8 server but strange thing is, i can create directory but when i try to delete i get error `Transport endpoint is not connected`

Here is my mount point

```
$ mount | grep gluster
10.10.217.21:gluster_vol2/voyager on /mnt/glusterfs type fuse.glusterfs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,max_read=131072)
```

I have created dir

```
$ mkdir foo
$ rmdir foo
rmdir: failed to remove 'foo': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

But strange issue i can create file and successfully able to delete. I have verify basic things like firewall etc and all looks good. (I have no control on Gluster Storage so what else i can do from client side to debug?)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in the network.
The way to solve this is to remount the mountpoint:

```
sudo umount /mnt/glusterfs
sudo mount /mnt/glusterfs
```

Comment: Already did and couple of time but no luck. This was a first troubleshooting step.